# Unable to hide Drawer.screen label in react native 0.62?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import HomeComponent from '../../Home/index'
import ContactMeComponent from '../../ContactMe/index'
import AboutMeComponent from '../../AboutMe/index'
import BlogComponent from '../../Blog/index'
import { MainStackNavigation } from '../../StackNavigations/MainStackNavigation/index'

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export function MainDrawerNavigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
    independent="true">
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
      drawerContentOptions= {{
        activeTintColor:'#000000',
        labelStyle: {fontFamily: 'comicNeueRegular'}
    }}>
        <Drawer.Screen 
         name="MainStackNavigation" component={MainStackNavigation} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeComponent}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={AboutMeComponent} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Blog" component={BlogComponent} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Contact" component={ContactMeComponent} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

In the above code, i want to hide Drawer.screen label of name="MainStackNavigation". How can i do it? 
I am using react native 0.62. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably just create a custom drawer component and render it using drawerContent prop as mentioned in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/

Comment: I am using nested navigation, so it will not work. Is there some way to hide this label from drawer menu?

Comment: why wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this once. Create a class which return null as follow

```
class Hidden extend React.Component{
render(){
return null;
}
}
```

and then add options to drawer like

```
export function MainDrawerNavigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
    independent="true">
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
      drawerContentOptions= {{
        activeTintColor:'#000000',
        labelStyle: {fontFamily: 'comicNeueRegular'}
    }}>
        <Drawer.Screen 
         name="MainStackNavigation" component={MainStackNavigation} options = {{drawerLabel: <Hidden />}} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeComponent}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={AboutMeComponent} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Blog" component={BlogComponent} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Contact" component={ContactMeComponent} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Hope it will work

Comment: kindly make sure that you put double curly braces for options

Comment: Or else try this. It worked for me <Drawer.Screen name="Test" component={Test} options={{ headerShown : false}}/>